# Alcohol vaporization by 5%, How much liters remained in the bottle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, percentages

**Problem:**

"There is a 30% solution of alcohol in water in a bottle of 6 liters. Some of the solution is vaporized, with twice (2x) as much alcohol vaporized than water. After the vaporization the remaining solution is 25% alcohol.

What is the total amount of new amount of liters inside the bottle after the vaporization occurred?

**Solution attempt:**

$alcohol=2*water \space \to vaporized$

initial values: $$alcohol \to \space 0.3*6l=1.8l$$

$$water\space\space  \to \space 0.7*6l=4.2l$$
$$alcohol=water*2; \space $$
$$------------------------------$$

$$1.8-(0.25*1.8)=1.8-0.45=1.35l \space\space  alcohol \space left$$
$$0.45/2=0.225l \space\space  water\space  reduction$$
$$amount_{new}=1.35+ (4.2-0.225)=5.32l$$

The result should be **5.28**.

What did I miss?

Comment: Your first paragraph is not clear. Did you mean something like this? "There is a 30% solution of alcohol in water in a bottle of 6 liters. Some of the solution is vaporized, with twice as much alcohol vaporized than water. After the vaporization the remaining solution is 25% alcohol."

Comment: That is yes, I will copy and paste it to the question if thats more understandable

Comment: I don't know why you thought a quarter of the alcohol escaped. Here's how I view it. Before reaction: $a_1+w_1=6,a_1=0.3(a_1+w_1)$. After reaction: $a_2-a_1=2(w_2-w_1),a_2=0.25(a_2+w_2)$. 4 equations in 4 unknowns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have six unknowns $a_\text{start},w_\text{start},a_\text{ev},w_\text{ev},a_\text{left},w_\text{left}$ and six equations:
$$a_\text{start}+w_\text{start}=6$$ 
$$a_\text{start}=0.3 (a_\text{start}+w_\text{start})$$ 
$$a_\text{ev}=2w_\text{ev}$$
$$a_\text{left}=0.25 (a_\text{left}+w_\text{left})$$ 
$$a_\text{ev}=a_\text{start}-a_\text{left}$$
$$w_\text{ev}=w_\text{start}-a_\text{left}$$
then you can solve these to give 
$$a_\text{start}=1.8$$ 
$$w_\text{start}=4.2$$ 
$$w_\text{left}=3a_\text{left}$$ 
$$(1.8-a_\text{left})=2(4.2-3a_\text{left})$$
$$a_\text{left} = 1.32$$
$$w_\text{left} = 3.96$$
$$a_\text{ev} = 0.48$$
$$w_\text{ev} = 0.24$$

and that gives the total amount left as $a_\text{left}+w_\text{left}=5.28$

A single calculation just using the numbers in the question could be $\dfrac{ 2 \times 6 \times (1-0.3) - 6 \times 0.3}{1 +0.25}=5.28$ but I think that would be less clear

Answer (score 2):

Originally, the solution contained $1.8l$ alcohol and $4.2l$ water.

Let the volume of water that evaporates be $x$, then the vol. of alcohol that evaporates is $2x$.

The final alc. concentration is $25 \%$ ($1$ *in* $4$). That means the final proportion of alc. to water is $1:3$ ($1$ *is to* $3$).

So $3(1.8 - 2x) = 4.2 - x$

$x = 0.24$

Hence the total volume that evaporates is $3x = 0.72l$, giving a final volume of $6- 0.72 = 5.28l$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}
&
\hline
&\text{Water}&\text{Alcohol} &\text{Total}\\
\hline
\;\; \text{Original}&4.2 &1.8 &\color{blue}{6.0}\\
&(70\%)&(\color{blue}{30\%})&(100\%)\\\\
-\text{Evaporated}&-V &-\color{blue}{2}V &-3V\\\\
\hline\\
\;\; \text{Balance (Final)} &4.2-V &1.8-2V &\color{green}{6-3V}\\
&(75\%) &(\color{blue}{25\%}) &(100\%)\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
$$6-3V=4(1.8-2V)\\
\Rightarrow V=0.24$$
Hence final total volume of $\color{red}{5.28\ell}$.

---

NB: Colour code as follows:

$\color{blue}{\text{Blue}:}$ Given
$\color{green}{\text{Green}:}$To be determined